# Making a density plot

Tags: r, heatmap, density-plot, spatstat

I am using the longleaf data in `spatstat` where the marks attached to each point pattern is the diameter of the trees.  I have created a density colour map plot of the data. But instead of the colours relating to the density of the trees I want to colour map to relate to the diameter of the trees.

For the density colour map plot of the long leaf data I have this and I have attached the plot.

```
plot(density(longleaf))
plot(longleaf,add=TRUE,main=NULL,axes=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Please state clearly what you are trying to achieve: A coloured symbol at each location of the point pattern with different colours corresponding to different diameters? Or a colour image representing somehow the average tree diameter if you look around at the closest trees?

Comment: Hi sorry yes, a colour image representing the average tree diameter if you look around the closest trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spatstat` function `Smooth()` (notice the upper case S) smooths the
mark values across space:

```r
library(spatstat)
plot(Smooth(longleaf), main = "Smoothed tree diameters.")
plot(longleaf, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Did this solve your problem @alex? Then please mark the question as answered so it doesn't appear as unresolved in searches.

Comment: Yes it did thank you. How do I do that? New to this site.

Comment: There should be a check mark under the voting arrows next to the question you can press so it turns green (see <https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979> for the location of the check mark if you can't find it).